# Nested flexcontent using Wordpress ACF fiels

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber, acfpro

I'm using ACF's flexcontent, however to allow the user to add different types of content in the same row, I've nested more flexcontent elements inside it.

The goal for the end user to be able to add either text or image, and drag them to decide the order.

I have other types of flexcontent for images, video, text etc. These are working fine.

The structure of my ACF fields is

```
--text
--image etc (all other flexcontent blocks)

--content_mixed = flexcontent
----column = flexcontent
--------text= flexcontent
----------------text (text field)
--------image=flexcontent
----------------imagegroup (group)
--------------------------------image
--------------------------------caption
```

My code is:

```
{% set flexcontent == post.get_field('flexcontent')%}
{% if flexcontent %}
{% for item in flexcontent %}
{% if item.acf_fc_layout == 'text' %}
{% elseif item.acf_fc_layout == 'images' %}
//images
{% elseif item.acf_fc_layout == 'content_mixed' %}
   // text + image, this shows up
    {% for subitem in post.subitem.get_field('column') %}
        {% if subsubitem.acf_fc_layout == 'text' %}
            //text
        {% endif %}
        {% if subsubitem.acf_fc_layout == 'imagegroup' %}
          // image
         //image caption etc
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I think I'm in the wrong iteration but having trouble finding how to get to the right one. I can't see any of the content I've added to the post.

the print_r of {{ item.column }} (inside the first flexcontent field, "content_mixed") is

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [acf_fc_layout] => text
            [text] => 
Lorem Ipsum doret sit amet



        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [acf_fc_layout] => image
            [imagegroup] => Array


       (
                [image] => Array ( 
       //all image info
   )
```

Comment: What's your actual issue? Please state what your code is doing, and what you expected it to do instead.

Comment: You probably shouldn’t use `get_field()` on `post.subitem()`. Similarly to how you [shouldn’t use nested get_field() calls for repeaters](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#troubleshooting-repeaters), you shouldn’t do it for flexible content. Calling `post.get_field('flexcontent')` should already get everything you need to loop over.

Comment: @acobster I believe I'm in the wrong iteration, so I'm not seeing the fields. I will edit my post for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your `print_r` is telling you that `item` is an array of arrays. So you can just loop over that instead:

```
    {% for subitem in item.column %}
        {% if subsubitem.acf_fc_layout == 'text' %}
            //text
        {% endif %}
        // etc.
    {% endfor %}
```

As pointed out in the comments, your chained `post.subitem.get_field()` call will not do what you expect.

BTW, you don't need the `if flexcontent` check before your loop. Twig is very tolerant of empty values and will just ignore attempts to loop over `null`, `false`, etc. Less nesting is much easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use the % if flexcontent % mostly  to add a wrapper around it. I’ve followed your suggestions however I’m not able to print anything inside  subsubitem. As in, {{ subitem|print_r }} is empty so I’m unable to print the fields I’ve added to the Wordpress page